# Update a map windows phone mango

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps

I have a problem with the routing in a bing maps with windows phone mango. I need to update the map eliminating the old path when the user click on search everytime. I used the following guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx and it works, but when i search again on the map remains the old paths. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem. i inserted in xaml map an attribute MapPolyline "percorso" and this is the code  c#

```
 // If the route calculate was a success and contains a route, then draw the route on the map.
        if ((e.Result.ResponseSummary.StatusCode == BingMapRouteService.ResponseStatusCode.Success) & (e.Result.Result.Legs.Count != 0))
        {
            this.percorso.Locations = new LocationCollection();
            // Retrieve the route points that define the shape of the route.
            foreach (Location p in e.Result.Result.RoutePath.Points)
            {                   
                Location location = new Location();
                location.Latitude = p.Latitude;
                location.Longitude = p.Longitude;
                this.percorso.Locations.Add(location);
            }
```